# Stop Visual Studio for Mac 2019 from opening a browser tab when running .NET Core Console App

Tags: .net-core, visual-studio-mac

EDIT: I thought this was wrong behaviour from just starting a .NET Core Console App, BUT, I start listening to a TCP port right at the start of the application with `var listener = new TcpListener(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 5000));`, and this is when the browser window is opened. I am sorry for the confusion, if anyone knows if there is a way to NOT open a browser window when you start a TcpListener that would be great though.

Comment: That is odd. Looking at the Visual Studio for Mac source code launching the browser should not be enabled for a .NET Core console app. Depending on what VS Mac version it is enabled by default for ASP.NET Core projects. Is there a way to reproduce this so I can take a look?

Comment: Hm, I was trying to critical a minimal project to reproduce and indeed, the issue seems to be when the application starts listening to a port... in another words, this: `var listener = new TcpListener(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 5000));`. Sorry, my question is definitely wrong, this is the first .net core console app I write and I already started adding stuff so from the first time I tested it was opening the browser already...

Comment: Which versions of .NET Core sdk and Visual Studio for Mac do you have? I am not seeing the same behaviour but I am using VS Mac 8.1. Also does it happen if you use `dotnet run` from the command line in the project's directory?

Comment: huh... interesting, using `donet run` does NOT trigger it to open the browser... Im using  Visual Studio for Mac Community, v8.0.9 (build 5)

Comment: Oh and the project SDK is Microsoft.NETCore.App (2.1.0)

Comment: Not managed to reproduce this with a new .NET Core console project, VS Mac 8.0.9 and .NET Core 2.1.505 SDK installed. VS Mac 8.0.9 should use the launchUrl defined in the Properties/launchSettings.json file but only if the .csproj's Sdk attribute is Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web.